# magento shipping information, the continue button not working

Tags: php, magento, checkout

Please, I need your help!

After my magento installation, I am trying to buy a product (locally), but at the checkout step, after I fill the shipping information and click "Continue" nothing happens. I tried to visit almost all the online sources about this issue and do what they suggest, but still can't pass this step. Any advice please? Here is my billing.phtml file's buttons container content:

```
<div class="buttons-set" id="billing-buttons-container">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?>" class="button" onclick="billing.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
        <span class="please-wait" id="billing-please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you provide the link of your site?

Comment: Dear MTM, thank you for your will to help me. As I wrote it in my post, I m working locally, so no way to provide a link. However, I came out of the problem, by just installing Magento 1.8.0.0 instead of using v1.9.

Comment: how about clear the var/cache/* and disable cache at cache management, admin page. billing.phtml, is it still in persistent folder?

Answer (score 1):

try this.
go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/ file payment.phtml 
open it, find line 36

```
<fieldset>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

add id to fieldset

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, and the common answers did not help to me.

Doing some debug over the store i have noticed this error:

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open()

So, the mcrypt module wasnt installed on my VPS server, you need to install that module in order to get some Magento features working.

The process to install this module is the following:

apt-get install php5-mcrypt

restart apache and you are done!

Sometimes your distro may ask you to do apt-get update.